# Creating an AD application using .net

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to create an AD application using .net, I am able to create it with  Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient. But why I am supposed to create a native AD Application in the Azure portal prior to creation of AD Application in .net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, will I be able to create a AD application without client Id of a native app?

In short **no**.

When you [create application](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/application_post_applications) you need to **require Delegate permission or Application permission**. To assign the permission to user, you need to use app to act as an agent.

[image]

You could use the following code to get the ad token, you need to give the `client id` of the **native app** which you have **granted delegate permission**. You also could **grant Application permission to a Web app/API** which you use `client id` and `client secret` to acquire token.

```
var result = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(graphResourceId, clientId, new UserPasswordCredential(userName, password));
```

BTW, Azure portal is an enterprise application.So, when we login and create Azure AD App, it also get the client id of azure portal.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply publish your native .NET application using AAD Application Proxy. There are a number of samples that show how to do this. You need to publish your application through the application proxy and register it as a Native app.

This document details all of the steps for this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-proxy-configure-native-client-application

Comment: I think you didn't get my problem. I am able to create a AD application via .net using Graph API, for which I am supposed to provide a client Id of a native app with delegated permissions. My question is, will I be able to create a AD application without client Id of a native app?